# Implementing a trie over a Binary Search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, trie

I am trying to build a trie using one of the data structure which is a BST(Binary Search Tree).

**My question is how would the binary search tree look like?
I mean the normal BST would have the reference of right node, left node , and a value.**

**Will the structure change if I am trying to build a trie?**

Comment: Trying to implement a Trie using a BST, if even possible, will be difficult and will not be pretty. A Trie is a totally different data structure. However, I'm sure you can store the same data in a BST that you would in a Trie, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I thought if i use BST, it will be faster in searching. However, I sort it out now. I will have three references of the node (right, left and down). down that gets you the next character in dic. Cheers